# Program sends me to Error function, how to change it to ItayVAT?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, error-handling, python-requests

Every single time i run it it sends me to the error function

```
 def error():
    print("Something happened")

def ItalyVAT():
    print("yay")

def CountryL(Origin):
    if Origin == "1":
        ItalyVAT()
    else:
        error()

def main():
    Origin = int(input("Please enter number"))
    CountryL(Origin)

main()
```

How do I change it to ItalyVAT function?

Comment: your taking the input and converting it to an int. Then passing that to countryL. However countryL then compares that to the string value of 1 not the int. So its like saying `if 1 == "1"` whcih is false. since they are not the same. Either leave origin as a string or change the if to compare ints

Answer (score 2):

As @ChrisDoyle said in the comments, you cant check `Origin = "1"` when you are converting the input to an int before you send it to the function.
Either to this:

```
 def error():
    print("Something happened")

def ItalyVAT():
    print("yay")

def CountryL(Origin):
    if Origin == 1:
        ItalyVAT()
    else:
        error()

def main():
    Origin = int(input("Please enter number"))
    CountryL(Origin)

main()
```

Or this:

```
 def error():
    print("Something happened")

def ItalyVAT():
    print("yay")

def CountryL(Origin):
    if Origin == "1":
        ItalyVAT()
    else:
        error()

def main():
    Origin = input("Please enter number")
    CountryL(Origin)

main()
```